# Setting up BlackFire.io on a MAMP Pro installation (Mac OSX)

Tags: php, mamp

I'm having a great deal of difficulty getting BlackFire.io up and running locally on my my Mac OSX (10.10) and MampPro (3.2.1) setup.

I've been able to follow most of the instructions successfully, but have believe that OSX's native PHP/Apache install is taking some of the installation commands and not my MAMP config.  So far, finding any documentation that relates to the MAMP environment is lacking.

Is there a way to clearly delineate the two so that I can ensure the BlackFire plugins and configs are directed to my MAMP install?  Or perhaps is there a way to remove OSX's PHP/Apache?

Anyone else successfully got it up and running in this environment?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to install the PHP probe in the right folder (where MAMP'S PHP executable is).

Run `php -i | grep 'extension_dir'` and download the probe from [here](https://blackfire.io/docs/up-and-running/installation#installation-instructions) under the **Manual** tab.

After that, edit php.ini (File > Edit Template > PHP > Your PHP version), and add the configuration at the end of the file:

```
[blackfire]
;Replace the path with the path of the folder where you downloaded the probe
extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/blackfire-php-darwin_amd64-php-55.so"

; On Linux systems, uncomment the following line
;blackfire.agent_socket = unix:///var/run/blackfire/agent.sock
; On Mac OS X systems, uncomment the following line
blackfire.agent_socket = unix:///usr/local/var/run/blackfire-agent.sock

blackfire.agent_timeout = 0.25

; Log verbosity level (4: debug, 3: info, 2: warning, 1: error)
blackfire.log_level = 4

; Log file
blackfire.log_file = /tmp/blackfire.log

blackfire.server_id = YOUR_SERVER_ID

blackfire.server_token = YOUR_SERVER_TOKEN
```

Comment: Thanks for the help on this, finally got it working! Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to follow their instructions for the agent and CLI, but had to manually get the probe working with MAMP.

Here's what I did to get the probe working on OSX 10.11.6 with MAMP 4.1, and PHP 7.1:

1. Download the appropriate `.so` extension file from [here](https://blackfire.io/docs/up-and-running/installation#installation-instructions), under the Manual tab, under the "Installing the PHP Probe" section.
2. Run `which php` to see if `php` in your command line is using the same version as MAMP. If it is, skip to #3. If it isn't:

   If it isn't, you may need to set your environment variables. There's a few ways to do it. I usually just do it for my user like so:

   Figure out the path to the version of PHP MAMP is using. Then add

   ```
   export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/bin:$PATH
   ```

   to `~/.bashrc`, then run `source ~/.bashrc` to have the changes take effect.

   If `which php` still isn't pointing to MAMP's PHP, consider searching for solutions for this before continuing.
3. Copy your downloaded `blackfire.so` file to the extension directory for PHP:

   ```
   /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303
   ```

   (or similar)
4. Figure out where PHP's ini is with `php --ini`. It's probably somewhere like `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/conf/php.ini`
5. Update your `php.ini`:

   ```
   ;Replace the path with the path of the folder where you downloaded the probe
   extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/blackfire-php-darwin_amd64-php-55.so"

   ;Replace the path with the path of the folder where you downloaded the probe
   extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/blackfire.so"

   blackfire.agent_socket = unix:///usr/local/var/run/blackfire-agent.sock

   blackfire.agent_timeout = 0.25

   ; Log verbosity level (4: debug, 3: info, 2: warning, 1: error)
   blackfire.log_level = 4

   ; Log file
   blackfire.log_file = /usr/local/var/log/blackfire/blackfire.log

   blackfire.server_id = YOUR_SERVER_ID

   blackfire.server_token = YOUR_SERVER_TOKEN
   ```

   Get the server ID and token from the section of [this page](https://blackfire.io/docs/up-and-running/installation#installation-instructions) that was *just over top* of where you downloaded the `.so` extension.
6. Restart Apache: `sudo apachectl restart`. You might need to do `stop` and `start` instead of `restart` if MAMP is causing issues.
7. Verify that the extension is there and has the configuration: `php --ri blackfire`

If all of that worked, you should be good to go now.